# How do i work with filenames with whitespaces in linux script?

Tags: scripts

I'm trying to use filenames loaded from a directory.

It works fine but once the filename has whitespaces it doesn't work.

**I'll demonstrate:**

Assume your in folder **`scriptExample`** with three filename `dummy file one`
, `dummy file two` , `dummy file three`.

My scripts performs simple `cat` command for each file

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in *
        do    
                cat $i
        done
```

**However when you run this you get:**

```
cat: dummy: No such file or directory
cat: file: No such file or directory
cat: one: No such file or directory
cat: dummy: No such file or directory
cat: file: No such file or directory
cat: three: No such file or directory
cat: dummy: No such file or directory
cat: file: No such file or directory
cat: two: No such file or directory
#!/bin/bash
for i in *
    do
        cat $i
    done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply surround your variable (`$i`) with double quotes:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in *
do
    cat "$i"
done
```

See also:

- [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)